# does ubuntu 14.04 use ascii-armor and how to turn it on/off?

Tags: 14.04, security, ascii

does ubuntu 14.04 use ascii-armor and how to turn it on/off?
the purpose is to test some exploit and knowing that would help, I'm still in the learning process.
I'm already aware of the stack protector with canaries and ASLR and how to turn them on/off in order to try some exploit techniques.
is there other security policies that ubuntu 14.04 follow that I should be aware in my journey into security/exploit?

thank again for all the answers

Comment: Ascii armor looks interesting, but I have a feeling asking if Ubuntu uses it is like asking if a truck can pull a RV or a tractor. Just a type of PGP an application might use, if I understand correctly?